# Embed Sound in CSS in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to use sound in flex. I got the output using urlrequest, as I have less sound files to use, and need not to load everytime i call it. So I tried to put that in css and use it, but I am getting an error : `TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.`

Below is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

<mx:Style>

draw
{
   url:"Assets/Sound/Active.mp3";
}

</mx:Style>

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

      import flash.media.Sound;
      import flash.media.SoundTransform;

    internal var sound:Sound;
    internal var soundVolume:SoundTransform;

 public function playSound():void
    {
        var SoundClass:Class;

    try
    {
            SoundClass = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("draw").getStyle("url") as Class;
            soundVolume = new SoundTransform(1, 0);
            trace("sound : "+sound);
            sound = new SoundClass() as Sound;
            sound.play(0, 0, soundVolume);
    }
    catch(E:Error)
    {
        trace("E "+E);
    }
    }

]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Button click="playSound()" label="Discard"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
draw {
   url:Embed(source="Assets/Sound/Active.mp3");
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/google/communityengine/index.cfm?postId=12146&productId=2)

Comment: Hello @Timofei, Sorry to bother you after long time. The above code worked for me, but the css is showing the error `Cannot transcode sounds of bitrate 48000Hz`. If I descrease the bitrate, the sounds are getting weird. Please let me know how to add higher bitrate sounds in css. My sound file size is 21kb-31kb with 48000Hz and higher bitrate(Approx). Thanks